# Dropbox api limitations

Tags: php, api, dropbox

Is it possible to use dropbox api to show directly to my webpage the content of a folder which is on my dropbox account and to allow dropbox users to add content to it (directly from my website too) considering that I'm rather an amateur than a professional coder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd likely be interested in the Dropbox [Chooser](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/chooser) and [Saver](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/saver) JavaScript widgets that allow you to do something similar.

You can also check out the [Kloudless File Explorer](https://github.com/kloudless/file-explorer/) for one that works across several cloud storage services, if your users don't use just Dropbox. (I work at Kloudless)

Comment: Thanks that was exactly what I was looking for !

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox has released a preview of a new pre-built component for embedding files and folders! You can find more information about the Dropbox Embedder in our blog post here:

https://dropbox.tech/developers/new-file-and-folder-embedder-launched-in-preview

There's also a chance to win a $200 Amazon gift card if you fill out a survey about the new Dropbox Embedder. Check out the blog post above for more information.